# jQuery dropdown menu plugin of apycom fails in firefox

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I am using [dropdown menu from Apycom](http://apycom.com/menus/1-deep-sky-blue.html) for http://prakriti.alwaysdata.net/

Everything works fine in Google Chrome, Safari and IE. But, in Firefox, dropdown menu does not work as expected, I can't click on them and nested links are not visible either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem now. Problem was due to mistake in CSS stylesheet. z-index for wrapper was in negative. corrected it and is now working.